# Finding distinct pairs {x, y} that satisfies the equation 1/x + 1/y = 1/n with x, y, and n being whole numbers

Tags: algorithm, math

The task is to find the amount of distinct pairs of {x, y} that fits the equation 1/x + 1/y = 1/n, with n being the input given by the user. Different ordering of x and y does not count as a new pair.

For example, the value `n = 2` will mean `1/n = 1/2`. `1/2` can be formed with two pairs of {x, y}, whcih are `6 and 3` and `4 and 4`.

The value `n = 3` will mean `1/n = 1/3`. `1/3` can be formed with two pairs of {x, y}, which are `4 and 12` and `6 and 6`.

The mathematical equation of `1/x + 1/y = 1/n` can be converted to `y = nx/(x-n)` where if `y` and `x` in said converted equation are whole, they count as a pair of {x, y}. Using said converted formula, I will iterate `n` times starting from `x = n + 1` and adding `x` by 1 per iteration to find whether `nx % (x - n) == 0`; if it yields true, the `x` and `y` are a new distinct pair.

I found the answer to limit my iteration by `n` times by manually computing the answers and finding the number of repetitions 'pattern'. `x` also starts with `n+1` because otherwise, division by zero will happen or `y` will result in a negative number. The modulo operator is to indicate that the y attained is whole.

Questions:

- Is there a mathematical explanation behind why the iteration is limited to `n` times? I found out that the limit of iteration is `n` times by doing manual computation and finding the pattern: that I only need to iterate `n` times to find the amount of distinct pairs.
- Is there another way to find the amount of distinct pairs {x, y} other than my method above, which is by finding the VALUES of distinct pairs itself and then summing the amount of distinct pair? Is there a quick mathematical formula I'm not aware of?

For reference, my code can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/TakeNoteIAmHere/596eaa2ccf5815fe9bbc20172dce7a63

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that x,y,n > 0 we have

Observation 1: both, x and y must be greater than n

Observation 2: since (x,y) and (y,x) do not count as distinct, we can assume that x <= y.

Observation 3: x = y = 2n is always a solution and if x > 2n then y < x (thus no new solution)

This means the possible values for x are from n+1 up to 2n.

Comment: moreover it means that x+y divides x*y so x and y cannot be odd at the same time

Comment: ....you can also say: if `k(x)` is the set of prime factors of `x` then `k(x+y)` must be in `k(x) u k(y)`, right?

Answer (score 3):

A little algebra convers the equation

```
1/x + 1/y = n
```

into

```
(x-n)*(y-n) = n*n
```

Since we want a solution in integers, we seek integers f, g so that

```
f*g = n*n
```

and then the solution for x and y is

```
x = f+n, y = g+n
```

I think the easiest way to proceed is to factorise n, ie write

```
n = (P[1]^k[1]) * .. *(P[m]^k[m])
```

where the Ps are distinct primes, the ks positive integers and ^ denotes exponentiation.

Then the possibilities for f and g are

```
f = P[1]^a[1]) * .. *(P[m]^a[m])
g = P[1]^b[1]) * .. *(P[m]^b[m])
```

where the as and bs satisfy, for each i=1..m

```
0<=a[i]<=2*k[i]
b[i] = 2*k[i] - a[i]
```

If we just wanted to count the number of solutions, we would just need to count the number of fs, ie the number of distinct sequences a[]. But this is just

```
Nall = (2*k[1]+1)*... (2*[k[m]+1)
```

However we want to count the solution (f,g) and (g,f) as being the same. There is only one case where f = g (because the factorisation into primes is unique, we can only have f=g if the a[] equal the b[]) and so the number we seek is

```
1 + (Nall-1)/2
```

Comment: I see. This is really clever, but how did you know that you were looking for the equation `f*g = n*n` and that you had to find the prime factorisation for each probabilities, which amount is gotten by calculating the possibilities of the power of the primes?